# Change body text (fast way)

Tags: javascript

I need to change a specify text inside my body content.

I currently do it this way:

```
findAndReplace: function(str, value) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('%'+str+'%', value);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way? It gets very slow on big pages.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What are you trying to replace? How big is your page? Is there a better way you could target the replacements?

Comment: No, I cant give them an id or anything else

Comment: A more efficient way would be to target a specific element and change that only using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.body`. Why can't you give them an ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking the browser to do there is spin through all of the DOM elements, create HTML for them, hand that HTML to the JavaScript layer, accept the new HTML from the JavaScript layer, destroy all the old elements, and completely rebuild the page from the new string.

If the text you're replacing occurs only as text within elements (no *inside* tags, e.g. `<div not-here>but yes here</div>`), you may have better luck doing a recursive DOM walk:

```
walk(document.body, new RegExp('%' + str + '%', "g"), "the replacement");
function walk(node, target, replacement) {
  var child, text, newText;

  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case 1: // Element
      for (child = node.firstChild;
           child;
           child = child.nextSibling) {
        walk(child, target, replacement);
      }
      break;

    case 3: // Text node
      text = node.nodeValue;
      newText = text.replace(target, replacement);
      if (text != newText) {                // Profile to see if this test matters
          node.nodeValue = text;
      }   
      break;
  }
}
```

Note that I've used a regular expression there, because otherwise only the first occurrence is replaced. Beware that if `str` contains any characters that are special in regular expressions (such as `^`, `.`, `*`, and so on), you'll need to escape them. (Search for "javascript regexp escape" to find various implementations that will handle doing that for you.)

Two reasons this might be faster:

1. You're not asking the engine to generate HTML for every element on the page, destroy the elements, and recreate them
2. You're not needlessly updating the content of text nodes (but again, profile whether the test is really worthwhile)

It might also prevent issues with your scripts, e.g., if you hook up event handlers, then bludgeon `document.body.innerHTML`, your handlers aren't there anymore. With the above, they're untouched.